# Updating ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I never ran an ubuntu server, until recently, I needed a bigbluetutton VM, and, since installing on ubuntu it's easier (just add the repository), I installed it on that distro.

But, when I log on console, i get this:

> 24 packages can be updated. 0 updates
>   are security updates.
>
> *** System restart required ***

So I do apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, but it says no packages to upgrade.
How to update those 24 packages?

Comment: does 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' work? or you could first to a sudo apt-get update and then try dist-upgrade again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its a known bug.
the motd on the login does not get refreshed...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/545398

The duplicate motd resides in /etc/motd.tail, apparently the installer saves it there? Remove this file, and the motd is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get upgrade
```

will only upgrade those packages where the dependencies have not changed and therefore no other packages will be either removed or installed. If you want to upgrade all packages, you need to run

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: It updated some packages, i rebooted, but the logon message still says "24 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates."

Comment: Run it again, and let me know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove motd.tail as it doesn't get updated due to a bug in installer. All you need to do is run the following command to remove motd.tail and the motd will be fixed:

```
sudo rm /etc/motd.tail
```